# Executing a command after eth0 is available, but before DHCP client

Tags: debian, dhcp, init

I'm running Debian Weezy on an ARM board.  Right now I'm working around an issue with my network driver by running an ethtool command that limits the Ethernet interface to 100 megabit.  However, the issue with the driver manifests itself as early as DHCP negotiation, so I need to run ethtool before dhclient runs.

I've been trying to find a place where ethtool (or mii-tool, either way) can run before dhclient.  So far all of the places I've tried (`/etc/network/if-pre-up.d` and `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d`) won't work because "eth0" isn't present yet.

Is there a clean hook in the Debian network or system configuration where I can make changes to the Ethernet state before dhclient runs?  Or am I trying to do something impossible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to bring up the eth as "manual" then apply whatever arbitrary scripts you want to run, including sleeps to slow things down, and then call for dhclient at the end.
On Ubuntu it would look like this in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
pre-up /etc/network/pre-up-scripts/eth0.sh  ( one way to do it)
pre-up some-script-or-command  (another way)
up dhclient  eth0
```

The man page for interfaces is quite helpful.